# Change label to textbox on hyperclick click - mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to change a label into a textbox when the user clicks on the EDIT link. I am doing the same thing that is discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792502/change-label-to-textbox-on-edit-hyperlink-click), only difference is that I am using mvc razor syntax `DisplayFor` instead of using `<label class="text-info">Saghir</label>`.
I am not getting the desired result, please tell me where I am going wrong.

HTML:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @id = "#attribute", @class = "text-info" })
<a href="#" id="edit">Edit</a>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$('#edit').click(function () {
    var text = $('.text-info').text();
    var input = $('<input id="attribute" type="text" value="' + text + '" />')
    $('.text-info').text('').append(input);
    input.select();

    input.blur(function () {
        var text = $('#attribute').val();
        $('#attribute').parent().text(text);
        $('#attribute').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: why don't you use attrribute `contenteditable`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the razor syntax, but shouldn't `@id = "#attribute"`be `@id = "attribute"` ?

Comment: @Cornwell I tried with `@id = "attribute"` as well, but still not getting the result

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I din't get you, please give an example

Comment: @sumedha He meant something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cegpbhuc/

Comment: @Cornwell ok but how will the user know that, that particular field is editable. If I give an "Edit" link and then allow the user to edit the content, it would be more intuitive.

Comment: @sumedha You would need to add some css, but this basic example would fit your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/cegpbhuc/

Comment: @Cornwell but this doesn't work I just tried doing it

Comment: @sumedha Sorry I forgot jsfiddle didn't save changes. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/x1um7tkp/

Comment: @Cornwell yes it works now.thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try This one

HTML

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @id = "attribute", @class = "text-info" })
<a href="#" id="edit">Edit</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#edit').click(function () {
     var text = $('.text-info').text();     
     var input = "<input id='attribute' type='text' class='text-fill' value='" + text + "' onfocusout='myFunction($(this))' />";
     $('.text-info').parent().text('').append(input);         
   });
});

function myFunction(e){
  var text = e.val(); 
  var dad = e.parent();  
  e.remove();
  dad.append("<label for='name' id='attribute' class='text-info'>" + text + "</label>");
}
```

For Example Fiddle - http://jsbin.com/xegusicige/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for you answer @DineshJ but its not giving me the result. When the "Edit" link click event is fired, I can see this error in internet explorer's inspect element: "Object doesn't support property or method 'select'"

Comment: Wait i Share You fiddle.

Comment: @Sumedha Now check the fiddle once click Run with JS button in fiddle then check it

Comment: your fiddle is working for the first time but if I click on the edit link again, I cannot edit the field.

Comment: this is working when I use <label> but when I am using DisplayFor it is not showing me the result. Is it because of this : `dad.text("<label for='name' id='attribute' class='text-info'>" + text + "</label>");` if yes then how can I make it work

Comment: @Sumedha Use dad.append("<label for='name' id='attribute' class='text-info'>" + text + "</label>"). Check my answer also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112667/discussion-between-sumedha-and-dinesh-j).

Comment: Discussion Chat is not opening to me

Comment: ok maybe you do not have that many points to view the discussion. Anyways, when i click on the edit hyperlink nothing happens, I even did inspect element using firebug but I am not getting any errors also
dont know whats going wrong, did you test the answer that you posted using razor syntax? is it working in your end?

Comment: ok can able to share me you display for how it is render in browser check inspect element and share that tag

Comment: Its exactly the same html that you posted in this answer.

Comment: Can you put screen shot of it

Comment: I cant attach a screen shot in my comment, that option is not available here, but as I said I did not change anything in the html code `DisplayFor`, I only changed the javascript, accroding to the answer you posted. HTML is the same: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @id = "attribute", @class = "text-info" })
<a href="#" id="edit">Edit</a>`

Comment: I have sent you an email

Comment: can't get where its getting stuck. tried the same code posted by you, I am trying to figure out whats going wrong, as soon as I get it will post the answer here

Comment: ok give alert message inside the $(".edit").click(function (){ alert("text"); }); Check it any alert message came or not

Comment: This has already taken up a lot of my time, I tried a lot but did not get the desired result, so I decided to use the code as it is, instead of using Html.DisplayFor. I have taken it in a label `<label class="text-info">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FullName)</label>`

Comment: @sumedha once i have check it here if its work i inform you

Comment: ok. one more thing I wanted to ask is what if I want to do this for more than one label on the same page? how to pass the id.

Comment: More than one label is how u use the edit. one edit for one label or one edit for all the labels.

Comment: one edit for all labels. On click of the edit button all the labels should convert to texboxes and the user can edit the values. How to do this?

Comment: No need to change any thing this code will working fine for that

Answer (score 2):

From My comment:

```js
var textEl = document.getElementById("text");
document.getElementById("edit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  textEl.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
  textEl.focus();
}, false);
//per Dinesh J's suggestion:
textEl.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  this.setAttribute("contenteditable", "false");
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="edit">
  Edit!
</button>
<div id="text">
  Random text
</div>
```